# How to efficiently get the k bigger elements of a list?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, performance, python

What´s the most efficient, elegant and pythonic way of solving this problem?

Given a list (or set or whatever) of n elements, we want to get the k biggest ones. ( You can assume `k<n/2` without loss of generality, I guess)
For example, if the list were:

```
l = [9,1,6,4,2,8,3,7,5]
```

n = 9, and let's say k = 3.
What's the most efficient algorithm for retrieving the 3 biggest ones?
In this case we should get `[9,8,7]`, in no particular order.

Thanks!
Manuel

Comment: +1 Now that basic purpose is served let there be CODE-GOLF?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Use nlargest from heapq module

```
from heapq import nlargest
lst = [9,1,6,4,2,8,3,7,5]
nlargest(3, lst) # Gives [9,8,7]
```

You can also give a key to nlargest in case you wanna change your criteria:

```
from heapq import nlargest
tags = [ ("python", 30), ("ruby", 25), ("c++", 50), ("lisp", 20) ]
nlargest(2, tags, key=lambda e:e[1]) # Gives [ ("c++", 50), ("python", 30) ]
```

Comment: Great language ranking :) )

Comment: is it guaranteed that `nlargest()` would return items in the sorted order as mentioned in the above examples? couldn't find this in doc, so I guess, there is no such guarantee

Comment: ^ okay, I just read the source code, it seems the output would always be sorted. Nice!

Answer (score 18):

The simple, O(n log n) way is to sort the list then get the last *k* elements.

The proper way is to use a [selection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Selecting_k_smallest_or_largest_elements), which runs in O(n + k log k) time.

Also, `heapq.nlargest` [takes O(n log k) time on average](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471544/worse-is-better-is-there-an-example/472302#472302), which may or may not be good enough.

(If k = O(n), then all 3 algorithms have the same complexity (i.e. don't bother). If k = O(log n), then the selection algorithm as described in Wikipedia is O(n) and `heapq.nlargest` is O(n log log n), but double logarithm is "constant enough" for most practical *n* that it doesn't matter.)

Comment: from the link for nlargest in the answer, the time complexity seems to be O(n log(k)) and not O(k log(n))

Comment: It's k*logn, not n*logk, you binary search n elements (O(logn)) k times => O(k logn)

Answer (score 9):

```
l = [9,1,6,4,2,8,3,7,5]

sorted(l)[-k:]
```

Comment: sorted(heap) -> O(n logn) complexity

VS

heapify(heap) -> O(n)
+
heapq.nlargest(k, heap) -> O(k logn)

It's better to use the latter case

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `heapq` module.

```
>>> from heapq import heapify, nlargest
>>> l = [9,1,6,4,2,8,3,7,5]
>>> heapify(l)
>>> nlargest(3, l)
[9, 8, 7]
>>>
```

Comment: we don't need to heapify it here

Answer (score 4):

```
sorted(l, reverse=True)[:k]
```