# most efficent way of finding the minimum float in a python list

Tags: python, list

Quick question, which is more efficient for finding the smallest number (float) in a long list (10000+ elements)

is it

```
min(mylist)
```

or

```
mylist.sort()
```

and then returning

```
mylist[0]
```

or something else...

thanks!

Comment: I'm going to take a stab that `min` would not only be semantically more accurate, but will likely be implemented more efficiently since Python will know what to do, and `sort()` may not be the best thing to do.

Comment: Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289053/fast-way-to-get-n-min-or-max-elements-from-a-list-in-python for a duplicate

Comment: Was `timeit` broken?  This seems like a great opportunity to show the results from `timeit`.  Why didn't you post the `timeit` results?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the list is already populated, `min()` is the most efficient way.

There are some tricks you might use in special scenarios:

- If you build the list from scratch, simply keep the smallest item yet in an external variable, so that the answer will be given in `O(1)`.
- If there are only Floats in the list, use an [Array](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html) which gives better performance.
- You can keep the list sorted using [bisect](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7.1/library/bisect.html).
- Use a [Python Heap](http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest), which even has an efficient implementation of `min()`. Make sure you understand the effects, mainly a slower insertion. ([credit: interjay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289053/fast-way-to-get-n-min-or-max-elements-from-a-list-in-python))

Comment: thanks for the responses everyone - very helpful. On reflection i've realised I don't need to actaually keep all the values hanging around to do the final search for the lowest. All I need is to compare the current value in the loop with the min and do a little 'if a<b' type thing to make sure i'm getting the lowest. Must be better that way than carrying round a massive list of floats for no reason.

Answer (score 13):

Frst, if you care about performance in Python (which isn't always a sensible thing to care about, but that's another conversation), you should be using the [timeit module](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html).  Even in C it's hard to predict how certain functions will behave after compilation, and it's harder in Python.  People are often confidently expressing opinions about which functions are faster which are data-dependent.  Then -- by using timeit, I mean -- you could've found out yourself.

Second, if you *really* care about performance on lists of floats, you shouldn't be using lists at all, but numpy arrays.  Using IPython here, under Python 2.7.2, which makes timing things easy:

```
In [41]: import random, numpy
In [42]: a = [0.1*i for i in range(10**5)]
In [43]: timeit min(a)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.55 ms per loop
In [44]: timeit sorted(a)[0]
100 loops, best of 3: 4.57 ms per loop
In [45]: random.shuffle(a)
In [46]: timeit min(a)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.06 ms per loop
In [47]: timeit min(a) # to make sure it wasn't a fluke
100 loops, best of 3: 6.07 ms per loop
In [48]: timeit sorted(a)[0]
10 loops, best of 3: 65.9 ms per loop
In [49]: b = numpy.array(a)
In [50]: timeit b.min()
10000 loops, best of 3: 97.5 us per loop
```

And we note a few things.  (1) Python's sort (timsort) works very well on data which has sorted runs, so sorting an already sorted list has almost no penalty.  (2) Sorting a random list, on the other hand, is very much slower, and this will only get worse as the data gets larger.  (3) Numpy.min() on a float array works sixty times faster than min on a Python list, because it doesn't have to be as general.

Comment: +1 That's the best answer if the developer controls the construction of the list (as opposed to getting a handle as input)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you definitely have to iterate over the whole list, so your runtime should be O(n).

As a sort already takes O(n log n) time, this is obviously not the best way to do this. I do not know the implementation of min(), but it should be the right way to do this.