# Algorithm for finding the largest K numbers in a heap of size N in O(K) time?

Tags: algorithm

Can anybody think of an algorithm where the inputs are a heap A of size n and a value Y in which the algorithm will return all values in A that are >= Y.

Condition being that the run time must be O(k) (the number of elements we return).

I'm not looking for code, just a general outline of an idea to solve this problem. For instance assuming the Heap is a MAX heap then the array will be sorted from highest to smallest, in which case I can iterate through the array up until A[i] < Y.

I can only think of solutions using min/max heap, if the heap isn't in either of those cases I can't think of any solutions.

Comment: As described, I don't think it's possible.  To determine the values, you must perform a comparison against each value in the hep.  This constrains the algorithm to no less than **O(n)**.

Comment: If you are using Python, use heapq.nlargest(K): https://stackoverflow.com/a/2243562/584846

Comment: What else heaps do you mean except for min/max? General max-heap doesn't give you a sorted array of data.

Comment: Do you mean "the largest K numbers" (as in the question's title) or "the numbers greater than Y"? I assume it is the latter, in which case there is a solution and you need to fix the title. If you mean the largest K numbers, there is no linear-time solution.

Comment: @rici There exists a linear solution for "largest K numbers" as well. I posted it as an answer but it was deleted as a link-only answer. Please refer to the paper "An Optimal Algorithm for Selection in a Min-Heap" by Frederickson ([link](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0890540183710308)).

Comment: @JimMischel Thanks. Just to note - I deliberately didn't post such link to avoid possible legal issues, I don't know this site's policy about it.

Comment: @IvanSmirnov: [This paper](http://www.cs.au.dk/~gerth/advising/thesis/kenn-daniel_casper-faergemand.pdf) appears to have no such restrictions, and provides much better description of the algorithm and experimental results. I've removed the other link.

Comment: @ivan that's fascinating. I stand corrected.