# How can I compare one of the components within an element of a tuple? The function input a tuple (str, int) I to access the int only

Tags: python, tuples

Like I was mentioning, I would only like to compare the int, the code that I have tried is  resulting in

> **TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'tuple'.**

> input:[('Mikayla', 20), ('Kevin', 25), ('Tristan', 10), ('Moe', 30)]

> output:[('Moe', 30), ('Kevin', 25), ('Mikayla', 20)]

```
winners = []
max = 0 
int_val = 0

for i in range (0,2):            # find 3 values
  for j in range(len(scores)):  # look thru all of the tuples
    if scores[j][1] > max:     #compare int val from tup to max
      max = scores[j]         # assign a full tup (str,in) to  max 
    winners.append(max)      #append max to new array
    scores.remove(max)      #remove from old array
return winners             #return list of winner tuples (str,int)
```

Comment: Provide some expected inputs and outputs please

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Get out of the habit of using `for index in range(len(list)):`. Use `for item in list:`

Comment: Don't modify the list that you're iterating over.

Comment: Are you trying to get the three highest scores? If so, you might be interested in [`heapq.nlargest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest). Specifically, `winners  = heapq.nlargest(3, scores, key=lambda x: x[1])` or `winners = heapq.nlargest(3, scores, key=operator.itemgetter(1))`.

Comment: You're welcome. In future, you may get better answers here if you clearly describe your goals.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to efficiently get the k bigger elements of a list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243542/how-to-efficiently-get-the-k-bigger-elements-of-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Since `max` is a tuple, you need to index it to get the score to compare with:

```
if scores[j][1] > max[1]:
```

Also, don't use `max` as a variable name. It's the name of a built-in function.